# VisualD. Using external .lib

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-7, d

I am developing a project under Visual D. In solution I have one library project and one executable project. The question is how to link library project (to use modules from there) in executable project?

I tried to add library search path in project settings but that didn't take effect and compiler still wrote that error:

```
Error: module TestObject is in file 'Library\Core\TestObject.d' which cannot be read    D:\dev\projects\d\MySolution\Executable\main.d
```

**Update 1**
After some experiments, I discovered that problem is with compiler linker. I installed Xamarin Studio, added lib and executable projects, checked lib project as dependency for exectutable project, Xamarin Studio found (!!!) modules and namespaces from lib project, **but** compiler still wrote that stupid error. In Xamarin build log full qualified path to lib binary is present. (For reference, I am using Windows 7 x86)

**Update 2**
I pushed my project to [GitHub](https://github.com/chief93/ZetaBox), if you want to try to compile it - you're welcome.

**Update 3**
I already have tested compilation in MonoDevelop on fresh Ubuntu 13.10, and there is still presents that error. I think that maybe my problem with orginizing file structure or project structure...

Comment: is there an option for VS for an include/import path? (I've never used it, but the error there is that it can't find the import .d module rather than the library .lib)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried to find theese options but unsuccessfull =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that problem is with file structure. For some strange reason, in D you can not create nested projects with same module name like

Core\MyClass.d:

```
module Core.MyClass;

class MyClass {
    //some stuff
}
```

and then to use it like:

```
import Core.MyClass;
```

because when you link a lib, it namespace will mixin in your global namespace, but module structure will not be followed. Will be followed file structure like module structure. This happens on **all** compilers (*dmd*, *dmd2*, *ldc2*, *gdc*). And this is very strange, because *C#* or *ActionScript* allow this and this is normal logic. Any ideas how to organize some structure like below?

```
import Root.Sub.Target;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a .d file that has all the function prototypes and types in it, like a C header file. In that file, you can add a line `pragma(lib, "TestObject");` to tell the compiler it needs to link with that module. I believe modules are searched for in the standard -I import paths, so try adding your module path there.

Comment: Can You tell where that file need to be located?

Comment: And it is correct to assume that -I option need to be in Visual D command line?

Comment: I have added -H compiler switch that adds di interface file, but that had not took any effect :(

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you have two projects in the solution and want the exe project to link automatically against the lib project ? You simply right click on the exe project in the solution viewer and add the lib as a Build Dependancy.

Comment: Which Visual Studio do you use? Which VisualD version ? As you see 
[here](http://www.dsource.org/projects/visuald/wiki/Features)
a main feature of VisualD is exactly that: "automatic link between dependent projects". I just tried using VS 2013 and VD 0.3.38-beta2 from [here](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/visuald/releases) and it works.
Alternatively you could try [mono-d](http://mono-d.alexanderbothe.com/) as an D IDE.
I also would recommend using the dub package manager to describe you project strucutre. It is able to generate the visuald solution files for you (inc dependancies)

Comment: As I said in the title, I use VS 2012. I'll try on VS 2013

Comment: no matter what, it should work, have VS2012 here too and it works. Look for "Build Dependancies" in the **context menu** when right clicking the exe project. In the pop up dialog you can make checkmarks on every depending project and visuald links them in.

Comment: I checked there my library project but that didn't work

Comment: Be sure that your library does compile and 'debug' the cmd scripts that visuald generates in order to build. you can actually trigger them from cmd line and see if the lib is added correctly to the linker. if you find any bugs please file a report [here](https://d.puremagic.com/issues)

Comment: I already checked linking and building arrangement. All is OK, but executable project still not compiling. Soon I'll try to add some screenshots for proof

Comment: First, thank You for your attempts to help me. Second, I tried to make empty **dub** solution, but when I have added there simillar project structure like my project, compilation failed with simillar error. Maybe I will write a bug report... P.S. Library project compiles with no errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46734/discussion-between-extrawurst-and-alex025)